# What am I doing wrong with the following code? I am using selenium for Python and for some reason, I get the error below

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/h90p8mrfk')
sleep(2)
addToCart = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
addToCart.click()
sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="button checkout"]').click()
sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_name').send_keys('Name')
browser.find_element_by_id('order_email').send_keys('email')
browser.find_element_by_id('order_tel').send_keys('phone number')
browser.find_element_by_id('bo').send_keys('address')
browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_zip').send_keys('zip')
Select(browser.find_element_by_id('state_label')).select_by_visible_text('state')
```

Everything in this code seems to work fine, until it is time to fill in the shipping/billing info.  I get this strange error that I can't find any answers on the internet as to what it means:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown
>   error occurred: A JavaScript exception occured: Argument 1 ('element')
>   to Window.getComputedStyle must be an instance of Element

The steps of the automated process I am trying to accomplish are:

1) Go to the actual webpage (Check)

2) Add the product to cart (Check)

3) Click the checkout button (Check)

4) Put in the billing/shipping info

Comment: Try `Select(browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_country')).select_by_value('BE')`

Comment: Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_

Answer (score 0):

it better to use `WebDriverWait()` than `sleep()`. selecting by `ID` not work use `XPATH`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/qfc4mhl9g')

addToCart = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
addToCart.click()

# wait max 10 second
checkOut = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="button checkout"]' ))
)

checkOut.click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'order_billing_name'))
)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="order_billing_name"]').send_keys('Name')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="order_email"]').send_keys('email')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="order_tel"]').send_keys('phone number')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="order_billing_zip"]').send_keys('zip')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="order_billing_address"]').send_keys('address')

state = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_state"]'))
state.select_by_visible_text('茨城県')
```